# Laravel 6. General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running through the error message below  after defining my database table engine to **innoDB**. I tried everything out there but it is not working. As you can tell I'm using `bigInteger` and `unsignedBigInteger` for my column type.

**Error**

> `Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table`users`add constraint`users_account_status_id_foreign`foreign key (`account_status_id`) references`statuses`(`id`) on delete set null on update cascade)`

```
 ************  USERS TABLE ***************************
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('phone')->nullable();
        $table->string('user_code')->unique();
        $table->integer('online_status')->boolean()->default(0);
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('account_status_id')->default(0);
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();

        $table->foreign('account_status_id')->references('id')->on('statuses')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('set null');
    });


*********STATUSES TABLE *******************
  Schema::create('statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
        // $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    });

******* CONFIG/database.php ****************
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        ...
        'engine' => 'innoDB',
        ...
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you haven't correctly defined the actual foreign key field on the **Users** table perhaps.  Before the `foreign` designation, I would expect to see something like:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('account_status_id');  // No default 0
$table->foreign('account_status_id')->references('id')->on('statuses')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('set null');
```

Note the loss of the `->default(0)`, as this will create problems against the nullable field.

The [docs for migrations are here for V6](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations).

Comment: I have he foreign key defined already `$table->unsignedBigInteger('account_status_id')->default(0);`

Comment: Try without the default though - you can't have a FK with a 0 - it can't match.  Nullable is OK, but the 0 is probably causing havoc with the cascade null

Comment: No change. It's getting me sick now :). Everything looks like nice but this crazy error keeps prompting

Comment: I know the feeling :)  Are BOTH tables running innoDB?

Comment: I removed the onDelete as you mentioned and the migration run successfully. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I think your Schema Builder fails to create foreign key constraint because STATUSES TABLE is not already created.

Try to reverse migration orders (Change the dates that form the first part of the migration filenames so they're in the order you want (eg. for 2020_01_09_134109_create_users_table.php, the date & time is 2020-01-29, 13:41:09)

Run the migrations again.

Comment: How to reserve the migration  order?

Comment: Change the dates that form the first part of the migration filenames so they're in the order you want (eg. for 2020_01_09_134109_create_users_table.php, the date & time is 2020-01-29, 13:41:09

Comment: I changed `2019_12_16_060000_create_users_table.php` and `2019_12_15_053624_create_statuses_table.php` so that he statuses migration runs first but still facing he same issue

Comment: Did you drop all tables from db and tried
php artisan migrate:fresh

Comment: Yes, I'm running `php artisan migate:fresh`